# Deletion using checkboxes in struts2 application

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2

I want to implement delete functionality using checkboxes in my struts2 application. I'm using display tag in my jsp page to show the reports. I need to provide checkboxes with reports to delete the selected reports. I have tried this code in my jsp page :

```
<s:form name="listPage">
<display:table name="egnreports" class="table" id="egnreports" requestURI=""  export="true" pagesize="30">

<display:column>
 <s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue='%{egnreports.id}' />
</display:column>

<display:column value="<%=egnreports_rowNum%>" title="S.No." />

<display:column property="createDate" sortable="true" titleKey="egnreport.createDate" style="width:13.5%"/>

<-- Other Table data here -->

</display:table>
</s:form>
<c:out value="${buttons}" escapeXml="false" />
```

In my action class, I have used this :

```
 private String[] checked; 

public String[] getChecked() {

    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(String[] checked) {

    this.checked=checked;

}
```

When I try to retrive the selected values to delete the corresponding reports, I get a null pointer exception :

```
for (String code : checked) { 

    System.out.println(code + " is selected"); 
    System.out.println("id="+egnreport.getId());
        egnreportManager.remove(egnreport.getId());
        saveMessage(getText("ireport.deleted"));
        }
```

If I use

```
<display:column>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="${egnreports.id}"/>
 </display:column>
```

in place of s:checkbox tag, I'm able to see the values in the reports page (using firebug), but still they do not get populated in the action class.

using

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="${egnreports.id}"/>
```

i get

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="checked"> </td>
```

as rendered html, while with

```
<s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue='%{egnreports.id}' />
```

I get

```
<td> 
<div id="wwgrp_egnDeskReports_checked" class="wwgrp"> 
<div id="wwctrl_egnDeskReports_checked" class="wwctrl"> 
<input id="egnDeskReports_checked" type="checkbox" value="" name="checked"> 
<input type="hidden" value="" name="__checkbox_checked"> 
</div> 
</div> 
</td>
```

Also I can't use `"${egnreports.id}"` with `s:checkbox` to get the values of id.
Where did I go wrong? can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Show the rendered HTML, that will tell us exactly what will come back to struts2 for processing (given the defaultstack)

Comment: @Quaternion: with <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="${egnreports.id}"/>, i get <td>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="checked">
</td> as rendered html, while with <s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue='%{egnreports.id}' /> , i get <td>
<div id="wwgrp_egnDeskReports_checked" class="wwgrp">
<div id="wwctrl_egnDeskReports_checked" class="wwctrl">
<input id="egnDeskReports_checked" type="checkbox" value="" name="checked">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="__checkbox_checked">
</div>
</div>
</td> . Also i can't use "${egnreports.id}" with s:checkbox to get the values of id.

Comment: I'm not going to read html in a comment, put it in the question!

Comment: i just did that. note that when i use input type, i get the id value as 5, but in case of s:checkbox, i'm not even able to get the values. However in both the cases, i'm not able to retrieve the checked values in my action class....

Comment: Can you add the xml or annotations... (or tell me if you are using the defaultstack or you made up your own interceptor stack)

Comment: i'm using the defaultstack....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have got the solution : i have to use  fieldValue="%{#attr.egnreports.id}" i.e,

```
<s:checkbox name="checked"  fieldValue="%{#attr.egnreports.id}" value="false"/>
```

to pass the checked values.
Also remember to include buttons inside form tag, i didn't pay attention to this before:

```
<c:out value="${buttons}" escapeXml="false" />    
</s:form>
```

:-)